# SwiperJS looping triggers event twice

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

onSlideChanged triggers twice when you reach the end of the slider and keep sliding. I know this has something to do with the loop being set to true, but how do you make it so that the event onSlideChange only triggers once whether it's looped through the entire items or not?

```
<template>
  <swiper
    :navigation="true"
    :modules="modules"
    @slideChange="onSlideChange"
    loop
    class="mySwiper"
  >
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</template>
<script setup>
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import { Navigation } from "swiper";

const onSlideChange = (swiper) => {
  console.log("called");
};

const modules = [Navigation];
</script>
```

Sandbox Demo:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-vue-navigation-forked-2xeot1?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A27%2C1